# Trouble with importing simple .txt file to Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am unable to get Python to read a simple table shown in the image
[image]

Below is the code I am using, and I have the code file saved in the same folder as the 'simple_table.txt' file so it should open without calling the full path to the file which I have also tried and still does not work.  When I run the code, I get a 'finished with exit code 0', so my code does not seem to have any errors.  Anything that I am missing.  Code Shown Below.

```
import pandas as pd

number_list = pd.read_table('simple_table.txt')

print(number_list.shape)
```

Comment: Besides, "finished with exit code 0," does your code print anything else?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""

Created on Tue Dec 29 11:38:07 2020

@author: bob
"""

import pandas as pd

number_list = pd.read_table('simple_table.txt')

print('printing : ',number_list.shape)
```

run it:

```
printing :  (9, 1)
```

no error